# Django url pattern not recognizing email

Tags: python, django

My url pattern is

```
url('^auth/login/(?P<user_name>\w+)/(?P<password>\w+)/$', views.auth_login_from_device, name='login_from_device'),
```

when I call localhost:8000/auth/login/myname/12345, it is perfectly fine

But when I call
 localhost:8000/auth/login/me@mymail.com/12345/

I get 
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/login/satya@prakash/12345/

The current URL, auth/login/satya@prakash/12345/, didn't match any of these.

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^$', views.auth_index, name='auth_index'),
    url('^auth/login/$', views.auth_login, name='auth_login'),
    url('^auth/login/(?P<user_name>\w+)/(?P<password>\w+)/$', views.auth_login_from_device, name='login_from_device'),
)
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should *never* show the password in raw text, what are you trying to do with this url/view?

Comment: This request will be sent by mobile device so I didn't care about sending raw password in request. Anyway what should be my approach?

Comment: The device the request is coming from isn't important. At the very least in needs to be encrypted. preferably it should never be in the url at all. ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in

```
url('^auth/login/(?P<user_name>\w+)/(?P<password>\w+)/$'
```

you are taking the `user_name` as `\w+`, however `\w+` won't match `@`

try this:

```
 url('^auth/login/(?P<user_name>\w+@\w+)/(?P<password>\w+)/$'
```

with the `@` contained in the regex

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more thing: I had also tried                                                    url('^auth/login/(?P<user_name>\[A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&+=]+)/                        but this did not work. Why?

Answer (score 4):

The `\w` in `(?P<user_name>\w+)` does not match the `@` sign.

It would be better to use `[\w.@+-]+`, which matches several other characters that appear in emails. That is the approach used in the [Django code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7c0850028f25eebaa9b521b5d02afac084ff2c6f/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L311)

```
url('^auth/login/(?P<user_name>[\w.@+-]+)/...
```

**Note that having the password in the url is a very bad idea!** It means that the password will be saved in the browser's history, server logs and so on.

Comment: url('^auth/login/(?P<user_name>[\w.@+-])/...      is not working

Comment: There was a missing `+`, I've added it now.

Comment: Now working but strangely, having the same pattern for password is not working

Comment: If the password is not working, then the regex does not match the password for some reason. However, as I said before, please don't put the password in the url!